# Data of file exported to Excel and CSV varying

Tags: python, pandas

I am exporting a dataframe to an Excel as well as a CSV file. Certain columns have data in the format of integers. These values are being shown as integers in Excel and the dataframe output. But, they are being shown as decimals in the CSV file.

```
pd.to_numeric(column_name, errors = 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Expected Result

```
1
1
2
3
1
2
4
```

Actual Result

```
1.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
1.0
2.0
4.0
```

Comment: Did you assign the column back to itself or pass it `inplace=True`?

Comment: If we knew how the csv file is produced, maybe be we could guess why it contains numbers in floating format. As my crystal ball is currently out of use I cannot help without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'number': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df.number=pd.to_numeric(pd.to_numeric(df.number), errors = 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
df.to_csv('test.csv' ,index=False)
```

Output:

```
   number
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
```